# Cant find Svcutil.exe on my machine

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I have a visual studio 2015 on my machine I try to search for the svcutil.exe but I can't find it.  Do I need to install it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find the last version:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

also unofficial links:

[download svcutil.exe](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/SvcUtil.shtml)

[download svcutil.exe](http://originaldll.com/file/svcutil.exe/31570.html)